# remove duplicating fields in php-mysql result rows

Tags: php, mysql

After I executed a query and loop through the result to compose an array of records, when I var_dump that array, I see the following:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string '1'
      'id' => string '1'
      1 => string 'record one'
      'name' => string 'record one'
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string '2'
      'id' => string '2'
      1 => string 'record two'
      'name' => string 'record two'
```

what should I do to turn the above into the following?

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'id' => string '1'
      'name' => string 'record one'
  1 => 
    array
      'id' => string '2'
      'name' => string 'record two'
```

Comment: please consider to accept an answer (click tick mark on the left) if it actually answered your question

Answer (score 2):

Don't use [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php). Use [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php). (Or the Mysqli equivalents)

Answer (score 1):

fetch the data from your database with...

```
     $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) // <--- _assoc!
```